# jquery disabled other options when one is selected

Tags: jquery

I wrote this jquery to disable all the other options when one is select, however I am trying to make it so I don't have to copy and past this for each option (i.e. quanity-2, quanity-3, etc.)

Is there a way to change this to list all the options and then have it disable everyone except for the one that changed?

```
$("#quantity-1").change(function () {
    if ($("#quantity-1").val().trim() != "0") {
        $("#quantity-2").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-3").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-4").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-5").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-6").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-7").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-8").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-9").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-10").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-11").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#quantity-12").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $("#quantity-2").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-3").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-4").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-5").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-6").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-7").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-8").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-9").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-10").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-11").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#quantity-12").prop('disabled', false);
    }

});
```

Comment: Use a class instead of id. Then get all of them and filter out the current one from the list. Set status of all the selected at once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over here instead of ID you can use class and then trim all the values.
now, you can disable other values but not the current.

You can try something like this.

```
$(".quantity-input").change(() => {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val().trim();
    $(".quantity-input").not(this).prop('disabled', selectedValue != "0");
});
```